# How do I get the default member and owner SPGroups?

Tags: permissions, groups

I want to show members and owners in a webpart. My site collection can be created in different languages, so I can't get needed groups like `web.Groups["Contoso Members"]`. Because it may be "Medlemmar på Contoso" or something else.

When I ran `$web.Groups` I saw Members group had id 5.

Can I trust this id number? Or is it random number?

```
SPGroup members = web.Groups[5]
foreach (SPUser user in members.Users)
{
   //show it
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't count on that number, as it's just the index within the collection.

The **AssociatedMemberGroup** and **AssociatedOwnerGroup** properties on **SPWeb** should give you what you're looking for without having to know the actual name of the group.